# How to find the schema name of a data pump dmp file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, datapump, impdp

I have been given a DMP data pump export file to import into my local Oracle instance.  I've tried running this command line:

> impdp full=Y directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=MyDumpFile.dmp logfile=import.log

I get the errors:

> ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
>
> ORA-39154: Objects from foreign schemas have been removed from import

And no data is imported.

From what I've Googled, one possible cause of this is that I need to specify `remap_schama`.  But I have no idea what the name is of the schema in the dmp file.  Any easy way to find out?

**EDIT:** I didn't find a solution to this question, but I did find a workaround... I tracked down the guy who made the DMP, and <s>beat</s> got the schema name out of him.  Specified `remap_schema` according to his definition, and Hey Presto!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: the beat workaround worked fine for me as well. bePpe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `sqlfile=` parameter of `impdp` to generate a file containing all of the DDL/DML in the dump.

For example:

```
[oracle@oel61 ~]$ impdp phil/phil directory=oracledmp dumpfile=phil.dmp logfile=phil.log sqlfile=philddl.txt

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Wed Mar 13 15:15:03 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
Master table "PHIL"."SYS_SQL_FILE_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "PHIL"."SYS_SQL_FILE_FULL_01":  phil/******** directory=oracledmp dumpfile=phil.dmp logfile=phil.log sqlfile=philddl.txt 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "PHIL"."SYS_SQL_FILE_FULL_01" successfully completed at 15:15:05

[oracle@oel61 ~]$
```

Looking for `CREATE USER` DDL statements in the file should show you what schemas are needed in order to perform an import.

For example, from my test dump:

```
-- new object type path: SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
-- CONNECT SYSTEM
 CREATE USER "PHIL" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:924B2E756404611021428644B4DF06A4A7BAB886837FCCFA510151E0FC44;181446AE258EE2F6'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "PHILDATA"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";
-- new object type path: SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "PHIL";
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO "PHIL";
-- new object type path: SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
 GRANT "DBA" TO "PHIL";
-- new object type path: SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
 ALTER USER "PHIL" DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
```

The only drawback is that if the .dmp file is large the resulting SQL dump will be huge.

Comment: What is that first parameter `phil/phil'?  What should I be replacing it with?

Comment: It's the username and password....

Comment: D'oh! ..... :-)

Comment: Hm, all I got was this: -- CONNECT PS
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10150 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10904 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '25475 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10407 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10851 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '22830 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 192 ';

Comment: Courtesy ping - I found the original schema name.  So the question is kinda moot now...  Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: My answer will work with full=y and a user with appropriate privs (or login with "/ as sysdba").

Comment: I'll take your word for it! ;-)

Comment: Hasn't Oracle provided a nonclunky solution yet?
If some employee there could answer questions...